# How to know where the Elastic Search Hits are coming from

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elastic search cluster.

Currently designing a python service for client for read and write query to my elastic search. The python service will not be maintained by me. Only internally python service will call our elastic search for fetching and writing

Is there any way to configure the elastic search so that we get to know that the requests are coming from python service, Or any way we can pass some extra fields while querying based on that fields we will get the logs

Answer (score 0):

There is no online feature in elasticsearch to resolve your request. (you want to check the source and add fields to query).

but there is a solution for audit logs.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enable-audit-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is placing a proxy in front of it and do the logging there, we have an Apache in front of our Elastic clusters to enable SSL-offloading there and add logging and ACL possibilities.

Comment: we did some changes on URL queries with haproxy.